# Scrolling table with first row vertically fixed and first column horizontally fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a table where the first row stays fixed at the top when scrolling vertically, and the first column stays fixed when scrolling horizontally. Here are some images to illustrate:

[image]

Normal appearance

[image]

Horizontal scroll

[image]

Horizontal and vertical scroll

[This plugin](http://www.fixedheadertable.com/) also does what I want (see the demo with fixedColumn ON), but I don't want to have to rely on a third party plugin to do this.

Here's a rough [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3rvc9s1/) to show where I'm running into problems. Basically, anytime I use `display:fixed` or `display:absolute` on a row or column, it doesn't co-operate with the functionality of the scrollbars.

Comment: You can download the plugin and add it to your development environment, no dependency.  Also, the example Jquery affects the column headers, not the rows.

Comment: I tried implementing the plugin but it doesn't work. In the console, I get an error message, "Error: Invalid table mark-up". I checked the plugin's git under issues and found this https://github.com/markmalek/Fixed-Header-Table/issues/127 , which isn't at all helpful. Besides, I would rather know how to make my own implementation.